# Knockout JS with HTML to PDF converter

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I've searched all over the place for an answer to this, and maybe the answer is just that - it doesn't exist, but hoping someone has some magic.

I'm using Knockout to bind several forms on a page. This all works fantastically. However, trying to send these forms to PDF converter has proved a challenge.

The rendered HTML still appears Knockout-y. I've tried to get the rendered DOM with $('body').html() but I still get the HTML tags with data-bind attributes. Is there some way to get the final rendered pure HTML for passing to the PDF converter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the rendered elements before they are added to the DOM in the afterRender event. See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_3_using_afterrender_afteradd_and_beforeremove for more info.

If you need access to the final rendered elements, create a custom binding (http://jsfiddle.net/nE7kK/):

```
<body data-bind="getRenderedElements: viewModel">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: viewModel">
        <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
    </ul>
</body>

viewModel = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "Bungle", type: "Bear" },
    { name: "George", type: "Hippo" },
    { name: "Zippy", type: "Unknown" }
]);

ko.bindingHandlers.getRenderedElements = {
   update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
       // use timeout so browser has time to render the elements
       setTimeout(function() {
            var html = $(element).html();
            alert(html);
       }, 1000);
   }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Note: If you use virtual elements you should tell knockout to allow the getRenderedElements binding access to these elements, see: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html

Comment: I looked into that, but I am not sure how to get that back into the DOM itself to render a complete document to push to the PDF converter.

Comment: That works well except for input text fields. Those are a bit squirrely. Thanks for your answer!